Angular 17.3 input signal returning value, not function
Updating an Angular app with the new input signal; changes so far have behaved as documented; declared:
imageID = input<number>()
however in one component, the signal variable is returning the value, not the function, e.g.:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pic-captioned',
  templateUrl: './img-captioned.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./img-captioned.component.scss'],
})
export class ImgCaptionedComponent implements OnInit {
  caption = input<string>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this.caption:', this.caption); // this.caption Mississauga
    console.log('this.caption()', this.caption()); // ERROR TypeError: this.caption is not a function
  }
}

I’ve now determined the problem, why input behaves in some components but not in others:
The components where input misbehaves are all defined in app.module thusly:
    const imgCaptionedElement = createCustomElement(ImgCaptionedComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('img-captioned', imgCaptionedElement);

Possibly a bug in customElements that it hasn’t caught up with signals yet?

issue not reproducible stackblitz

created an issue on Github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/55739

This is a known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53981
